# Adding validation in an input field for options selected using Template driven forms in angular 13

Tags: angular, validation

I am new to Angular and got stuck in validation.

My problem is that I have dropdown menu with 4 options to select. when user selected one option I want an input field to change validation in such a way that:

If user select option 1 in the drop down than I want in the next input field to have the validation required and maximum length 8 numbers. likewise If the user select option 2 in the drop down. I want the input field to have the validation required and maximum length of 5 number. so i got stuck in validation how to do it. Any help and idea would be greatly appreciated## Heading ##

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please add a starting point in code so we can help you quickly. Also advised is to do the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use ReactiveFormsModule. Add in app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
   ...
   imports: [
       ...
       ReactiveFormsModule,
       ...
   ]
   ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

in your component *yourcomponent.component.ts*

```
maxlenght: number = 10; //default value
insertForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    selectType: ['', Validators.required],
    otherField: [''],
});

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

change() {
    this.maxlenght = +this.insertForm.get('selectType').value || 10;
    this.insertForm.get('otherField').clearValidators();
    this.insertForm.get('otherField').addValidators(Validators.maxLength(this.maxlenght));
}

isValid() {
    console.log(this.insertForm.valid);
}
```

in your component *yourcomponent.component.html*

```
<div [formGroup]="insertForm">
  <div>
    <select name="select" formControlName="selectType" (change)="change()">
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="13">13</option>
      <option value="14">14</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input formControlName="otherField" [maxlength]="maxlenght" />
    <small *ngIf="insertForm.get('otherField')?.errors" class="p-error">
      maxlength exceeded
    </small>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button (click)="isValid()">is valid?</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

for a complete example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1ajwxq?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: yes I got it...Thanks a lot but Can we also do this in template driven forms?

Comment: in template driven forms you haven't Validation in form and you have to do manually. An example of templete driven here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qy4fam?file=src/app/app.component.ts

In every case I suggest you to study in deep Reactive Forms. You can appreciate later this advice